# Prove that if $n$ is odd, then there is an $x$ for which $f(x) = -x^n$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Suppose $f$ is a function over reals and $n$ is a positive integer, for which  $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^n} =  \displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^n}= 0$. Prove that if $n$ is odd, then there is an $x$ for which $f(x) = -x^n$.

I am having difficulty thinking about how to relate the limits to the there exists an $x$ part. Since I only have to show that $f(x_0) = -x_0^n$ for just $x_0$, I think we can use the definition of a limit to our advantage here.

Comment: I think there is some hypothesis missing on $f$, because the statement seems false. How about this one? $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }-1<x<1\\0&\text{if }x\le-1\vee x\ge1\end{cases}$$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Hmm, it seems you are right. We must assume continuity. I am just quoting the question as written.

Comment: @AhmedHussein The second part of the question was "If $n$ is even, prove that there is a number $y$ for which $y^n+f(y) \leq x^n+f(x)$."

Comment: The second part also looks as if something is missing, since you could have $y=x$ and then it would be trivially true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $f$ is continuous, you can argue as follows:

If there is no $x$ such that $f(x) = -x^n$ then 
(from the intermediate value theorem):

- either $f(x) > -x^n$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$,
- or $f(x) < -x^n$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

In the first case it follows that $\dfrac{f(x)}{x^n} < -1$ for $x < 0$.
(Here it is used that $n$ is odd, so that $x^n < 0$ for $x < 0$,
and dividing by $x^n$ reverses the direction of the inequality.)

This contradicts 
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^n}= 0 \, .$$

The second case works similarly.

---

*Alternative "direct" proof:*

From $$
\lim_{x \to -\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^n} =  \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^n}= 0
$$
it follows that there are $x_1 < 0$ and $x_2 > 0$ such that
$$
 \dfrac{f(x_1)}{x_1^n} > -1 \text{ and } \dfrac{f(x_2)}{x_2^n} > -1 
$$
which implies
$$
 f(x_1)  < -x_1^n \text{ and }  f(x_2)  > -x_2^n \, .
$$
(Here it is used that $n$ is odd, so that 
multiplying by $x_1^n$ reverses the direction of the inequality.)

If we define $g(x) = f(x) +  x^n$, then $g$ is continuous and
satisfies
$$
 g(x_1) < 0 \text{ and } g(x_2) > 0 \, .
$$
It follows from the intermediate value theorem that there
exists an $x \in (x_1, x_2)$ such that $g(x) = 0$.

Comment: @Puzzled417: No. If $f(x) + x^n$ is continuous and takes both positive and negative values then it must be zero somewhere. That follows from the intermediate value theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem:

Comment: What if $f(x) > -x^n$ for some $x$ and $f(x) < -x^n$ for the rest of the $x$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: I tried to explain that in my previous comment.

Comment: What is wrong with $f(x)+x^n$ being $0$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: $f(x) + x^n = 0$ means that $f(x) = -x^n$, that is exactly what you wanted to show. – The above is an *indirect proof*: We assume that no solution exists, and then show that this implies a contradiction.

Comment: What about the second part: The second part of the question was "If $n$ is even, prove that there is a number $y$ for which $y^n+f(y) \leq x^n + f(x)$.

Comment: @Puzzled417: I have rewritten the answer to be "more direct". I hope that it  is clear now.

Comment: Actually I liked your indirect solution.

Comment: @Puzzled417: I prefer direct proofs :) – Now you have them both!

Comment: What about the second part which I posted above: "If $n$ is even, prove that there is a number $y$ for which $y^n+f(y) \leq x^n+f(x)$."

Comment: @Puzzled417: You mentioned that in a comment, but it is not part of this question. I would suggest that you post it as a new question.